# Iteratively subtract values in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting from a simple numpy array like:

```
a = np.array([1,1,0,2,1,0])
```

my goal is to iteratively subtract values from this till a certain threshold. For instance, think of `a` including number of users. In this case 5 users are distributed with:

```
d = a/a.sum()
```

Now I want to subtract 4 users at the time from this initial distribution, keeping always values > 0 in the resulting array. I can construct a random array to subtract with:

```
b = np.random.multinomial(4,d)
```

that generates (in a single run):

```
array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0])
```

The result like `a-b` leads to:

```
array([ 1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0])
```

How can I constraint that the generated array never produces a negative value in the resulting `(a-b)` operation? So far I thought in doing the things from the other side, generating a random distribution of:

```
r = np.random.multinomial(total users - deleted users,d)
```

according to the initial distribution of users `d`, but since I have to apply some metrics on the vector, results might vary in the latter approach.

Comment: can't you just do `np.maximum(a-b, 0)`? to ensure non-negative values in the result?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, but in that case I would "lost" users. The idea was to construct an array `b` that goes into subtract values to `a` only where `(a-b)>0`.

Comment: So something like `np.where((a-b) > 0, a-b, a)`

Comment: If `d` is defined as `a/a.sum()`, how do you get  `b[2]=1` where `d[2]=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to randomly decrement `a.sum()` by `n` without any element of `a` becoming negative, this is one way to do it:

```
def rnd_decrement(a, n):
    c = np.cumsum(np.r_[0, a])
    if n < c[-1]:
        r = np.random.choice(np.arange(c[-1]) + 1, n, replace = False)
        d = np.sum(r[:,None] <= c[None,:], axis=0)
        return np.diff(c-d)
    else:
        return np.zeros_like(a)
```

Comment: That's a very impressive solution, @daniel-f – I've been tinkering with it and looking for a way to pass different probabilities for the different elements in `a`, but that doesn't seem to be possible because you pick randomly from the `cumsum` array, right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Could probably do something with the `p` parameter of `random.choice`, but you'd be better off asking another question and linking this one if you want something efficient.